# how can I tell if someone has read text message?

Tags: sms

Does delivery report mean that the person reads the message on android phone?

Comment: Delivery reports mean that the message has been delivered to the recipient, not that it has been read.

Comment: thank you for the answers, then what is the difference between delivery report and if the message was sent?

Comment: Why is this tagged "text-prediction"?

Comment: use kik it lets you know if someone has read your msgs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, delivery reports generally just tell you that the message has been delivered and is sitting on their phone. It does not necessarily tell you that they've been read. There isn't a way to tell if its been read as far as I know.

Comment: In fact, there is nothing to prevent anyone from just deleting whole text message threads without reading them. If the sender asked for a confirmation, it is that it was delivered, only.

Comment: Thats ....what i said.

Comment: Right, but I was going for something along the line of "No one cares if you don't read your messages - but your carrier will certainly ding you for delivering it anyway, if your contract allows, including a fee for the receipt."

Comment: Point noted. The bit about the carrier potentially charging you is important.

Comment: There is a functionality for MMS messages that will give you a read report (distinct from delivery report, so you can get both a delivery report and a read report), but AFAIK, carrier and software support for this functionality is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Numerous Messenger apps provide the possibility to see if a person has read your message.

For text messages though, it is not possible to get a read status as it is not part of the SMS protocol.